# Losing all my text and entries on ColorWay Theme

Tags: themes, backup

I have hosted my website on a ec2. So when the ec2 goes down and I reboot it, I need to change the dns from the old to the new dns (micro instance).

Until now I was taking a manual backup of my wordpress page. I tar'ed the /var/www/website files to a tar, and mysqldump of the database to a sql file. And when I need to restore, I do a search replace in the sql file all localhost to that dns (where I am restoring) and untar the tar file to /var/www/website of my new host.

But with ColorWay theme, all my settings are lost. I wonder where else will a theme store all its data ? Am I missing something basic here ?

Infact any theme, I loose some setting or the other. Sometimes the menu choice, sometimes a few other settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And when I need to restore, I do a search replace in the sql file all
>   localhost to that dns...

Doing a find/replace in a text dump of the database will break the serialized data stored in theme options.

Use [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to correctly find/replace serialized data. Some simple themes without options don't serialize data, and a find/replace in a text dump is OK; but many themes will break.